# Youtube default LiveBroadcast being created without a bound stream ID

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

As part of our application flow, we create default LiveBroadcasts for the users to stream too. For most of our users the default LiveBroadcasts are automatically bound to the default LiveStreams, however a few users have default LiveBroadcasts that don't bind automatically.

I attempted to bind to a non-default LiveStream (since there seems to be no way to find the default LiveStream) and I get a `403` with an error message `liveBroadcastBindingNotAllowed: The binding is not allowed`.

Since there is no stream bound, we are unable to stream to that LiveBroadcast and our users are getting errors. Is there any workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue as well.  When listing all broadcasts via the following:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus&broadcastType=all&mine=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Some of our users are getting more than one broadcast where `snippet.defaultBroadcast` is `true`, but only one of these persistent broadcasts actually have a valid `contentDetails.boundStreamId`, the others simply omit the property.  For my personal account, if I change the broadcastType from `all` to `persistent`, then I'm able to get just the one true default broadcast which has a valid `contentDetails.boundStreamId`.  Here is an example request:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus&broadcastType=persistent&mine=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

I'm not sure yet if it's a fluke that it happens to choose the correct persistent broadcast.  I am going to contact some of our users to help me troubleshoot this, I know of one that has at least 3 persistent broadcasts in the response from the API.